# Spring Web MVC error handling for non binded parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring web mvc for registering an user. But my User class has a variable of type Website.

```
public class User{

private String email;

private WebSite website;

}

public class WebSite{

private String webSiteUrl;

}
```

In my registration form i need 2 text boxes for email and for webSiteUrl.

For email i am using the below way:

```
<label for="email">Email:</label> <form:errors path="email" cssClass="errors"/> 
<form:input path="email" required="true" placeholder="email@example.com" type="email"/>
```

How should i map webSiteUrl in jsp and its errors? I tried google but not able to find working solutions, can someone please help me.

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
<label for="website.webSiteUrl">Website:</label>
<form:errors path="website.webSiteUrl" cssClass="errors"/>
<form:input path="website.webSiteUrl"/>
```

Haven't tested, but should work..

Comment: Sorry @arun it doesn't work, throws an error
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'webSite' of bean class [com.richwp.richsalesagent.model.User]: Bean property 'webSite' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: @user988150: Sorry if I sound stupid, but can you please try "website"(with a small "s") in your jsp? I am saying this because your User class, the one you posted above, has a website with a small "s" and error message says "webSite" with a caps S